# General formula for error of an integration method

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods

Let $h > 0$ be a real number. For any function $f$, let
$$M(f) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N}w_if(x_i),$$
where the weights $w_i$ and the nodes $x_i$ are predetermined real numbers (they may depend on $h$, but $h$ is fixed). The weights and nodes are assumed to be obtained from integrating a polynomial interpolating the points $(x_1, f(x_1)), \dots, (x_N, f(x_N))$.
I am interested in the error of the approximation of $\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)\,dx$, which is given by
$$E(f) = M(f) - \int_{-h}^{h}f(x)\,dx$$

My approach so far is:
Let $n$ be the smallest nonnegative integer for which $E(x^n) \neq 0$.
For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, I can write
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)x^2}{2} + \dots + \frac{f^{(n)}(c(x))}{n!}x^n,$$
where $c(x)$ is between $0$ and $x$.
Since $E$ is a linear function,
\begin{align}
E(f) &= f(0)E(1) + f'(0)E(x) + \dots + E\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(c(x))}{n!}x^n\right) \\
&= E\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(c(x))}{n!}x^n\right).
\end{align}
From other derivations I have read, it seems that the error always can be written as
$$E(f) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}E(x^n)$$
for some $\xi$ in the smallest open interval containing the $x_i$, $-h$, and $h$. I am wondering how to get from my formula to this one. That is, how to show
$$E\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(c(x))}{n!}x^n\right) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}E(x^n).$$
So I want to show that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{N}w_i f^{(n)}(c(x_i))x_i^n - \int_{-h}^{h}f^{(n)}(c(x))x^n \,dx = f^{(n)}(\xi)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{N}w_ix_i^n - \int_{-h}^{h}x^n\,dx \right).$$
I've tried using intermediate value theorem and mean value theorem, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a counterexample using $$M(f) = 2hf(kh)$$ where $0 < k < 1$ is to be determined. We have that
$$E(x) = 2kh^2$$
is the first nonzero error. So the formula says that for any $f$ we should have
$$E(f) = 2kf'(c)h^2$$
for some $c \in (-h, h)$.
In the case of $f = x^2$ we get
$$E(f) = 2k^2h^3 - \frac{2}{3}h^3 = \left(2k^2 - \frac{2}{3}\right)h^3.$$
Therefore, the formula claims there exists $c \in (-h, h)$ such that
$$4kc = \left(2k^2 - \frac{2}{3}\right)h.$$
This means
$$c = \left(\frac{k}{2} - \frac{1}{6k}\right)h.$$
Taking $k = \frac{1}{100}$ gives
$$c = \left(\frac{1}{200} - \frac{50}{3}\right)h < -h$$
contradicting the statement.

One theorem that explains the general formula I was looking for is the [Peano kernel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_kernel_theorem), which does the same taylor expansion as I did, but uses the integral form of the remainder instead and pulls the $E$ inside the integral.